# C++ ifstream open many files

Tags: c++, ifstream

If i have about 19 `txt` file example file name: `13.txt` how should i open the `txt` file in sequence with the easy method in c++. Thanks for solving this problem.

Comment: add in your question, what have you tried.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
  std::istringstream iss;
  iss << i << ".txt";
  std::ifstream ifs( iss.str().c_str() );
  if(ifs) {
    // Do something with ifs
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

its quite simple create as many objects of ifstream as many files required to be manipulated. Becareful as this task is resource intensive